# Sort $5$ labeled balls into $3$ labeled bins such that no bin is empty

Tags: combinatorics

The balls and bins are all distinct, so the overall number of ways to sort the balls
into bins is $3^5$

The number of ways to sort all the balls into two of the bins is $2^5$, and there are $3$ choices for which bin to leave empty

The number of ways to sort the balls into one of the bins is $1^5$, and there are again $3$ choices for which bins to leave empty

So I would think the number of ways to sort the balls into 3 bins such that none of the bins are empty is $3^5 - 3 \cdot 2^5 - 3 \cdot 1^5 = 144$

Instead the answer is actually $150$, which interestingly is $3^5 - 3 \cdot 2^5 + 3 \cdot 1^5$

Instead of subtracting the case where two bins are empty, we add it. Why?

Comment: Hint: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

(Further Hint: Note that the case of two empty bins is already contained in the more general case of one empty bin. You need the different sign so as not to count the same event several times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that selecting one bin to be empty and then distributing the balls to the remaining two bins without restriction allows for the possibility that two bins are empty.  Subtracting the $3 \cdot 2^5$ cases in which we select an empty bin and then distribute the five balls to the remaining two bins without restriction subtracts those cases in which two bins are empty twice, once for each way we could have designated one of the two empty bins as the empty bin. We only want to subtract such cases once, so we must add them to the total, which is why there are $$3^5 - \binom{3}{1}2^5 + \binom{3}{2}1^5$$ ways to distribute five labeled balls to three distinct bins so that no bin is left empty.

Comment: Thank you. You mentioned that the initial subtraction counts the cases  where two bins are empty twice, once for each way we could've designated one of the two empty bins as the empty bin. Would this logic stay the same if we were instead sorting $5$ balls into $4$ bins? We'd first subtract ${4\choose 1}3^5$, but in doing so we have subtracted the cases in which two bins are empty twice? Or more than twice?

Comment: You would still be subtracting the cases in which two bins are empty twice, once for each way you could designate one of the empty bins as the empty bin.  Therefore, you would have to add the $\binom{4}{2}2^5$ cases with two empty bins to correct for that error.  However, you would not be done since you initially subtracted each case with three empty bins three times, once for each of the three ways you have designated one of those empty bins as the empty bin, then added them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways you could have designated two of those three empty bins as ...

Comment: the empty bins.  Consequently, you would have not subtracted those cases with three empty bins at all.  Therefore, we need to subtract them from the total.  The number of ways of distributing five distinct balls to four distinct bins so that no bin is left empty is $4^5 - \binom{4}{1}3^5 + \binom{4}{2}2^5 - \binom{4}{3}1^5$.  This is an application of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time inclusion-exclusion  has made sense to me